# Transformation between spaces with different dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

This might seem a very basic question. I would like to know if given a Hilbert space $V$, one can define a transformation over its elements that, to each element of the Hilbert space, a new state in a different **extended** Hilbert space can be constructed. For example, let $|\psi\rangle\in V$ define a state in the original Hilbert space. Then we seek for a transformation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Lambda&:& V\to B \nonumber\\ |\theta\rangle &=& \sum_{j}F_{j}|\psi_{j}\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
for $|\theta\rangle\in B$ being the new state in the extended Hilbert space $B$. So the transformation is not one to one, but rather, maps a state of the original space into another space with many more items.  Is that allowed and if so, under which conditions? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, transformations between spaces of different dimension are certainly allowed.  You are talking specifically about **linear** transformations so a space of dimension n would be mapped to a subspace of dimension less than or equal to n in a space of dimension m> n.  Such a transformation could be, with specific bases for the two spaces, written as a non-square matrix with n rows and m columns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, similarly, a state in V can be, by the inverse transformation, mapped to the extended B also in a linear fashion, right? In fact, what I want is to express the terms belonging to V as linear combinations of the elements of B, many thanks

Comment: IF  the linear transformation HAS  an  inverse!  Not every linear transformation does.